# Detecting structured data in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console, microdata, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets-tool

We have added some schema.org markup to a dozen of webpages on our website to provide rich snippets in Google SERP (different types, such as authorship and reviews). They are correct - at least, Google's Structured Data Testing Tool reports this.

However, even after a week we see the message "We do not detect any structured data on your site" in the Structured Data section in Google WMT. How long can it take while the Google bot detects our rich contents? Is there a way to speed up this process anyhow?

Comment: have you checked the page on Google about [Rich snippets not appearing](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1093493?hl=en)? Is all your code correct? Also, according to other questions like this one on different forums, it may take even a few weeks for it to appear, so it seems that you have to wait. If after that, you still have problems, go to the [rich snippets feedback](https://support.google.com/webmasters/contact/rich_snippets_feedback) and report it. But first wait and be sure that all items on your page are correct.

Comment: @PatomaS, we did check the pages using the Google Rich Snippet Troubleshooting guide - all is ok. I asked what is the reasonable amount of time we can wait for our rich snippets to be available in the SERP. As I can conclude from your comment, it is one month.

Comment: Yes, I'd say that a month is a reasonable time to wait, I know that it seems very long and probably it will be less than that, but considering one of the phrases from the second link; "Wait a few weeks—it may take some time for Google to crawl your site", we only know it may be a few weeks.

Comment: Google is in no hurry as you may know. It can take 30-60 days normally for changes to a site to filter out to the Google index. Much of that depends on two things; which Google instance you are looking at (not likely an issue except by country), and the freshness score Google has for your site. I have seen new pages get discovered, spidered, and indexed within 20 minutes from deployment on one of my older sites, but others can take as much as a year. It is frustrating sometimes. In regard to rich snippets, it may take a little bit longer but Google seems better about this lately. So hold on.

Comment: Don't forget to approve the answer if you like it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been through the same situation and saw nothing before 2-3 months on a small/new website. I think it is just Google being very slow at it. May be my site was not crawled often enough.

Comment: It seems, Google detected all our rich snippets in 3 weeks.