# Google Webmaster Tools: Structured Data (products)

Tags: google-search-console, structured-data

We have a store page using Magento. We've set up schema.org metadata to describe all products (about 16000). The [structured data tester](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) shows the data correctly.

Now, after a few months, GWT still shows only about 350 products, with a very very slowly rising tendency. All products shown are correct, but there are a ton more products not showing up. Is there a known reason why Ggoogle would not pick up most of the products? A sitemap containing all available products is regularily comitted.

Comment: It takes 3 months on average for those Rich Snippets to appear for small sites, websites that have a high volume of pages should expect to wait even longer. This only occurs on old pages, new pages that are created will be added far quicker. You just need to wait.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that it took this long. The crawls of the products Google does know about happen almost daily. It seems strange to single out these products. Is there a reference where I can read more about the delay and expected crawl rates for structured data?

Comment: Your assuming that every time Google crawls your site that it reflects all data captured during the crawl, sadly this is fact and not the case. Google may capture partially or fully capture details of the page, however not everything is computed at the same time, as much as it doesn't make sense, this is fact. Google Console, AKA Webmaster Tools is weeks to months behind on updating on certain things, again FACT.

Comment: Also, some websites get special treatment on search rankings, for example... Amazon will get updated faster, than a small-medium size businesses with a few thousand products, however this may not apply to WMT.  I'm not going to bother finding resources to backup my claims but have a general search on here [Webmaster Tools not updating](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=webmaster+tools+not+updating) & your see that on multiple subjects WMT is always behind, and rich data dates eons to update. May be worth mentioning that I've made around 20 sites with rich markup, it takes time.

Comment: Sorry but after reviewing the question I believe this has been asked several times over in various forms. Since your code is correct its merely waiting... there's many more questions like this already on Pro Webmasters [1](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34290/google-structured-data-dashboard-not-seeing-any-data) [2](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59332/detecting-structured-data-in-google-webmaster-tools) etc, search for rich markup, structured data and your find many that people are not waiting long enough.